# How to transform map object with carry forward previous object calculated value

Tags: java, java-8, java-stream

I have a class like this

```
class Transaction{
    long id;
    String type;
    long quantity;
    double amount;
}
```

And I want to convert it to like following

```
class TransactionDTO{
    long id;
    String type;
    long quantity;
    double amount;
    double total;
}
```

let's say the input as following

```
Transaction( id=1, type=buy, quantity=5, amount=5)
Transaction( id=1, type=buy, quantity=2, amount=3)
Transaction( id=1, type=buy, quantity=3, amount=6)
```

which should output as following `(quantity*amount adds when buy subtract when sell  with previous amount)`

```
Transaction( id=1, type=buy, quantity=5, amount=5, total=25)
Transaction( id=1, type=sell, quantity=2, amount=3, total=19)
Transaction( id=1, type=buy, quantity=3, amount=6, total=37)
```

I can do this easily with a for loop. But I am wondering if this can be done with `lambda`.

Specially looking to use previously calculated total with next element based on `Transaction type`.

So can this be done? If yes then how?

Answer (score 1):

You can do it like that:

```
public List<TransactionDTO> getTransaction() {
    double[] temporaryTotal = new double[1];
    List<Transaction> transactionList = Arrays.asList(
            new Transaction(1, "buy", 5, 5),
            new Transaction(1, "sell", 2, 3),
            new Transaction(1, "buy", 3, 6)
    );

    return transactionList.stream()
            .map(
                    transaction -> new TransactionDTO(
                            transaction.getId(),
                            transaction.getType(),
                            transaction.quantity,
                            transaction.getAmount(),
                            calculate(transaction, temporaryTotal[0])
                    )
            )
            .peek(transaction -> temporaryTotal[0] = transaction.getTotal())
            .collect(Collectors.toList());
}

private double calculate(final Transaction transaction, final double total){
    if (transaction.getType().equals("buy")){
        return total + (transaction.getQuantity() * transaction.getAmount());
    }

    return total - (transaction.getQuantity() * transaction.getAmount());
}
```

Since variable `total`  isn't final or effective final we can use array with one element named `temporaryTotal` .

Output is:

```
[TransactionDTO(id=1, type=buy, quantity=5, amount=5.0, total=25.0),
 TransactionDTO(id=1, type=sell, quantity=2, amount=3.0, total=19.0),
 TransactionDTO(id=1, type=buy, quantity=3, amount=6.0, total=37.0)]
```

Comment: I have changed an answer

Comment: Your answer should work but I do not want to do that array hack.
As i mentioned in my question I can easily do this using a for loop.
But I want make it perform better that is why I wanted to use lambda.
That arry hack seems not a good Idea. Please improve your answer if you can.

Answer (score 1):

It seems that the stream of `Transaction` should be grouped by `id` and `TransactionDTO` should provide a merge function to add/subtract quantity, amount and total depending on the `type`:

```java
class TransactionDTO {
    long id;
    String type;
    long quantity;
    double amount;
    double total;

public TransactionDTO (Transaction t) {
        this.id = t.id;
        this.type = t.type;

        int sign = "buy".equals(type) ? 1 : "sell".equals(type) ? -1 : 0;
        
        this.amount = sign * t.amount;
        this.quantity = sign * t.quantity;
        this.total = sign * t.amount * t.quantity;
    }

    public TransactionDTO merge(TransactionDTO t) {
        this.type = t.type; // store last type
        
        int sign = "buy".equals(type) ? 1 : "sell".equals(type) ? -1 : 0;
        
        this.amount += t.amount;
        this.quantity += t.quantity;
        this.total += sign * t.amount * t.quantity;

        return this;
    }
}
```

Then the list of `TransactionDTO` can be retrieved using `Collectors.toMap` and then transforming the map values:

```java
List<Transaction> transactionList = Arrays.asList(
        new Transaction(1, "buy", 5, 5),
        new Transaction(1, "sell", 2, 3),
        new Transaction(1, "buy", 3, 6),
        new Transaction(2, "buy", 2, 4),
        new Transaction(3, "sell", 1, 5)
);

List<TransactionDTO> totals = new ArrayList<>(
    transactionList.stream()
        .collect(Collectors.toMap(
            Transaction::getId, // key
            TransactionDTO::new,
            TransactionDTO::merge,
            LinkedHashMap::new // keep insertion order
        ))
        .values()
    );
totals.forEach(System.out::println); // assuming that TransactionDTO overrides toString
```

Output:

```
id: 1|type: buy|quantity: 6|amount: 8.0|total: 37.0
id: 2|type: buy|quantity: 2|amount: 4.0|total: 8.0
id: 3|type: sell|quantity: -1|amount: -5.0|total: -5.0
```